# Windows Terminal resize window with MODE

Tags: batch-file

Is there any way to run a .bat file with the `mode` command to resize the console window within Windows Terminal?

Because when I run the command while Windows Terminal is as default console, the command just doesn't work.
When I change the default console to CMD, the command works normally.

The command I'm using is:

```
@echo off
mode 75, 40

... rest of the code here ...
```

Comment: No. This has been a [known issue](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/5094) for quite a while. It appears to be stuck in the "there is no perfect solution for all scenarios, so let's have no solution" phase.

Comment: Got it, thanks a lot for the reply!
I'll see what I can do to get around this.